# How can I Include the related Entities but exclude the records where Deleted=true?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two Entities `EntityTest` and `EntityRelated`.

I want to query and get results from both Entites where Deleted is not true in both Entites.

I have tries below statement. It return EntityTest records by excluding records having Deleted = true but records of EntityRelated are not filtered.

```
db.EntityTest
.Include(i => i.EntityRelated)
.Where(x => x.Deleted != true && x.EntityRelated.Any(a => a.Deleted != true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Use this implementation of an extension method Include2() [Include2](http://blog.cincura.net/232741-include-with-filtering-or-limiting/). as following:

```
db.EntityTest
    .Include(i => i.EntityRelated.Where(e=>e.Deleted == false))
    .Where(x => x.Deleted != true && x.EntityRelated.Any(a => a.Deleted != true)
    .ToList();
```

Solution 1: